# "Get by on" or "Get by with"

Tags: prepositions

As you can see in [this link](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/get-by), Cambridge Dictionary has mentioned that we can use both prepositions "on" and "with" after the phrasal verb "get by", but I am not quite confident whether I can substitute these two prepositions here. For instance, I was wondering whether we can use "on" instead of "with" and vice versa in the following examples without any change in meaning:

> 1- We can get by **with** four computers at the moment, but we'll need a couple more when the new staff arrive.
>
> 2- I don't earn a huge salary, but I get by **on** it .

Comment: The dictionary is right.

Comment: Your selection is correct in both 1 & 2. You might use **on** in the first but it would be an awkward construction. **With** does NOT work in the second.

Comment: @RonaldSole: It works for me. If a trader can [*get by with a small profit*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22by+with+a+small+profit%22), I don't see why his employees can't *get by with a small salary*. I don't see much point in suggesting that learners need to acquaint themselves with two big lists of different things that "require, license" only one preposition or the other. But as a rule of thumb, ***with*** is a better fit in contexts where it could reasonably be replaced by ***using***.

Comment: Yes, generally one might say: I get by on my salary, but there is **no reason** one cannot say get by with it. They really do mean the same thing.

Comment: It seems to me that getting by *on* has the implication of survival on some possibly-meager sustenance while getting by *with* means having just enough resources to solve some problem. *On* works with the computer example, however, because being on a computer is idiomatic for operating or using a computer. I don't know how to confirm this hunch without more thought and effort than I can muster today.